# Array Varialble Touch Index

Tags: javascript, cross-platform, phonegap-build, smartface.io

I have a Variable of container (Ex: `var ConAdd[i] = new SMF.UI.Container({}};`),
adding list of Variable of images to my ConAdd(`var img[i] =  new SMF.UI.Image({});`) ,

Now it looks like repeat box but it was container where it have many images added,
but how to get rowIndex when I touch any image?

Answer (score 0):

For inner container objects there is no e.rowIndex value.
What operation do you want to perform when the image is pressed? If you want to change it and show another image, you can change it directly, you don’t need any value such as rowIndex.